# HTML5 Canvas: Calculating a x,y point when rotated

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas, trigonometry

I developing a HTML5 Canvas App and it involves reading a xml file that describes the position of arrows, rectanges and other shapes I need to to draw on the canvas.

Example of the XML layout:

```
<arrow left="10" top="20" width="100" height="200" rotation="-40" background-color="red"/> 
<rect left="10" top="20" width="100" height="200" rotation="300" background-color="red"/>
```

If the object is rotated it involves calculating the position of a point(called P the new position of the object after rotation) when rotated around another point(left,top). I am attempting to come up with a general function/formula I can use to calculate this point P but my Maths is a little weak & I cannot identify what arc/tangent formula I am meant to use.

**Can you assist me to come up with a formula I can use to calculate point P for rotations that can be both positive & negative?**

[image]

In the above example: point(14,446) is the left,top point & point(226,496) is the mid point of the object when NOT rotated so the point=(left+width/2,top+height/2) and the blue dot is the mid point when rotated. I know how to calulate the length of the line between points (14,446) & (226,496) but not how to calculate the blue point x,y position - BTW: the length of this line is the same as the line between the blue point & (14,446)

```
len = sqrt( (496-446)^2 + (226-14)^2 );
    = 227.56;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is quite simple. In rotation around the origin of the coordinate system for angle Theta coordinates (x,y) are changing as

```
x' = x * cos(Theta) - y * sin(Theta);
y' = x * sin(Theta) + y * cos(Theta);
```

So, all that you need is to translate point of rotation to one of the points that you have. Lets write it in a more simplified way: (x1,y1) = (14,446) and (x2,y2) = (226,496). You are trying to "rotate" (x2,y2) around (x1,y1). Calculate (dx2,dy2) in a new coordinate system with the origin at (x1,y1).

```
(dx2,dy2) = (x2-x1,y2-y1);
```

Now rotate (positive angles are counterclockwise):

```
dx2' = dx2 * cos(165 Degrees) - dy2 * sin(165 Degrees);
dy2' = dx2 * sin(165 Degrees) + dy2 * cos(165 Degrees);
```

The last step is to translate coordinates of the point from the origin at (x1,y1) back to the original (0,0);

```
x2' = dx2' + x1;
y2' = dy2' + y1;
```

ps: read also this :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix and do not forget that most trigonometric functions in different programming languages deal mostly with radians..

pps: and I hope that I did not scared you - ask if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3):

I think in your case you should be able to calculate this rotation position with the following system of equations:

```
x = R * Math.cos(angle - angle0);
y = R * Math.sin(angle - angle0);
angle  = deg * Math.PI / 180;
angle0 = Math.atan(y0/x0);
```

`R` the length of yor radius vector (`len` in your example).
`deg` angle in degrees you are rotating to, i.g 120°
`x` and `y` the coordinates of the final position your are looking for.
`angle` is the actual rotation angle (in rad, not grads).
`angle0` is the initial angle point was rotated to relativly to the X-axis. We need to precalculate it using `Math.atan`.

Haven't tested. So give it a try. But the idea is like that same - make use of trigonometric functions.

Comment: There is one thing that should be mentioned when you deal with arctangent... It will give the same angle when (x,y) is in I or in III quadrants and (x,y) is in II or IV quadrants. The correct value for angle should be chosen based on the signs of x and y.

Answer (score -1):

An example of coordinates calculation : [Dice roll](http://mamisab.chez-alice.fr/cube/dice_noprs.htm)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.