# HTML5 Canvas Calculating rotation point

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, html5-canvas, trigonometry

I am working on a canvas project based on a triangle pattern and I'm having problems with rotation. I would like to generate 6 of the same triangle then join them together by the sides. So far I have calculated the angle needed to rotate and generated the triangles.

I am using the rotation matrix formula described here: [HTML5 Canvas: Calculating a x,y point when rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043391/html5-canvas-calculating-a-x-y-point-when-rotated)
which almost works apart from the values are a little off.

```
x = (200-cX) * Math.cos(sAngle*radians) - (150-cY) * Math.sin(sAngle*radians) + cX;
y = (200-cX) * Math.sin(sAngle*radians) + (150-cY) * Math.cos(sAngle*radians) + cY
```

Here is my code so far: https://jsfiddle.net/bdrmm5n3/

I also almost got this working previously by changing the distance to 100 and modifying the center slightly but there are gaps in the pattern.

https://jsfiddle.net/7cezjnjo/

I'm guessing my center of rotation values are wrong after the shape has been rotated but I am not sure how to correct this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have solved this by calculating the difference between the points and translating the triangles like so https://jsfiddle.net/gwms568q/ although it would still be helpful to know where the formula goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your triangle configuration forms a regular polygon.

To calculate the centerpoint (==rotation point) of the regular polygon you need:

- a starting side point (p0),
- an ending side point (p1),
- the number of sides (sidecount)

**You can calculate the centerpoint like this:**

About this illustration:

- Blue dot is the known centerpoint (a target for the calculated centerpoint to hit)
- Gold line segment over the given side,
- Purple dot at the given segment's midpoint
- Green apothem line segment at 90 degrees from the midpoint
- Red dot at the end of the calculated centerpoint

[image]

```
function getCenter(sidecount,p0,p1){
    var dx=p1.x-p0.x;
    var dy=p1.y-p0.y;
    var sidelength=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    var sideangle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
    var apothemAngle=sideangle+PI/2;
    var apothem=sidelength/(2*Math.tan(deg2rad(180/sidecount)));
    var midX=(p0.x+p1.x)/2;
    var midY=(p0.y+p1.y)/2;
    var cx=midX+apothem*Math.cos(apothemAngle);
    var cy=midY+apothem*Math.sin(apothemAngle);
    return({x:cx,y:cy});
}
```

**Here's example code and a Demo**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// testing: get the vertices of a regular polygon
var points=regularPolygonPoints(cw/2,ch/2,7,75);
// draw the polygon
drawPoints(points,5,'black');
// draw a dot at the actual centerpoint of the polygon
// (we want to hit this centerpoint with our getCenter() function)
dot(cw/2,ch/2,'blue',8);

// some utilities
var PI=Math.PI;
var deg2rad=function(d){return(d*PI/180);}
// Given sidecount and starting+ending points of one side
var sidecount=7;
var p0=points[0];
var p1=points[1];

// ask getCenter to calc the centerpoint
var center=getCenter(sidecount,p0,p1);

// 
function getCenter(sidecount,p0,p1){
  var dx=p1.x-p0.x;
  var dy=p1.y-p0.y;
  var sidelength=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
  var sideangle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
  var apothemAngle=sideangle+PI/2;
  var apothem=sidelength/(2*Math.tan(deg2rad(180/sidecount)));
  var midX=(p0.x+p1.x)/2;
  var midY=(p0.y+p1.y)/2;
  var cx=midX+apothem*Math.cos(apothemAngle);
  var cy=midY+apothem*Math.sin(apothemAngle);

  // testing
  // draw a gold line segment over the given side
  // draw a purple dot at the given segment's midpoint
  // draw a green apothem line segment at 90 degrees from the midpoint
  // draw a red dot at the end of the apothem (==centerpoint)
  //
  // side line segment from p0 to p1
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p0.x,p0.y);
  ctx.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);
  ctx.lineWidth=3;
  ctx.strokeStyle='gold';
  ctx.stroke();
  // midpoint
  dot(midX,midY,'purple',7);
  // apothem line segment
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(midX,midY);
  ctx.lineTo(cx,cy);
  ctx.lineWidth=3;
  ctx.strokeStyle='green';
  ctx.stroke();
  // calculated centerpoint
  dot(cx,cy,'red',4);

  // return the centerpoint
  return({x:cx,y:cy});
}

function dot(x,y,color,r){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle=color;
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawPoints(points,linewidth,strokestyle){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
  for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(points[i].x,points[i].y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.lineWidth=linewidth
  ctx.strokeStyle=strokestyle;
  ctx.stroke();
}

function regularPolygonPoints(cx,cy,sideCount,radius){
  var sweep=Math.PI*2/sideCount;
  var points=[];
  for(var i=0;i<sideCount;i++){
    var x=cx+radius*Math.cos(i*sweep);
    var y=cy+radius*Math.sin(i*sweep);
    points.push({x:x,y:y});
  }
  return(points);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Draw a gold line segment over the given side
  <br>Draw a purple dot at the given segment's midpoint
  <br>Draw a green apothem line segment at 90 degrees from the midpoint
  <br>Draw a red dot at the end of the apothem (==centerpoint)
</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```